# MongoDB как файловое хранилище

Tags: mongodb, storage

Всем привет. Вопрос к спецам и тем у кого есть опыт с MongoDB.
Стоит задача организовать файловое хранилище, обемом порядка 100 ТБ, планирую реализовать на MongoDB, что можете сказать по этому поводу?

Comment: Вы занимаетесь cargo cult programming, знаете, что вам нужно *что-то хранить*, знаете, что база данных *позволяет что-то хранить*, и теперь пытаетесь это объединить, просто потому что формально используются одни и те же слова. Опишите свою настоящую проблему (какие файлы и как надо хранить, какой к ним должен быть доступ), и тогда вам дадут нормальный ответ, а сейчас можно ответить только то, что эту идею можно выкинуть и никогда к ней не возвращаться.

Comment: MongoDB любит писать максимум данных в оперативную память. Не думаю, что 100ТБ будет нормально работать, чем файлы не устраивают?

Comment: Нужно создать распределенное файловое хранилище, в котором будут размещаться файлы от текстового документа до фильма. Файловый вариант не подходит по причини что мне нужно распределенное хранилище.

Comment: ну так возьмите распределенное файловое хранилище, миллиард же их, хоть в гугл-облаке, хоть ceph у себя держать. но если требование по распределенности произрастает из такого же тумана, то у вас на самом деле не будет ни сотни терабайт, ни необходимости в этом инструменте, ни реальной пользы.

Comment: @ilyaplot c чего взяли это?

Comment: @Styvane работал с ней, хранил много текстовых данных, объем которых превышал размер оперативной памяти.

Comment: @ilyaplot Хранит она в файлах, но при выборке все грузит в оперативку, это факт, для того что бы это избегать можно делать индексы и использовать так сказать "Покрывающие запросы", да индексы съедят еще кучу физической памяти, но высвободят оперативку